# List of List of Integers get method not returning Integer

Tags: java

I need to compare value of `List<List<Integer>>` but I am getting the error: incomparable types: `Object` and `int`

Can someone help in getting a workaround?

Also, why is `val` an `Object` and not an `int`?

```
public class ArrayListExample{

    public static void main(String[] args){

      List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

         for(int i=1;i<10; i++){
         List<Integer> w = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          w.add(i);
          w.add(i+1);
          a.add(new ArrayList(w));
      }
      Object val = a.get(a.size()-1).get(1);

       System.out.println("Type is " + val.getClass().getName());

       if(val==9){
           System.out.println("--------------");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You literally declared `val` to be of type `Object` here yourself: `Object val`. Change that to `Integer`.

Comment: why are you using an `Object` in `Object val` ?

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to properly affect val. You already know this is an Integer because of the way the List of List is created

```
Integer val = a.get(a.size()-1).get(1);
```

Then, you can test your Integer value this way (as long as you are sure val will NEVER be null)

```
if (val.equals(9)) {
    System.out.println("--------------");
}
```